# CSS width acting strange

Tags: css, width, footer

Over at [this page](http://www.aquadual.com/) I'm having some trouble with the width of my foot `<div>`.  Is there an explainable reason why my footer is stretching the width of the browser window, while my header `<div>` isn't?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Your header is inside a table with width = 780px.  Your footer is inside a table with width = 100%.

Comment: Thanks, would you know how to align the text inside of this?  I've tried `text-align`, `margin` and `align`..